# regex mismatching integers

Tags: python, regex

For some reason I am having trouble capturing full dollar amounts in certain.

For example, I am searching through strings with:

> "$3,100 per box, $3,000.00 per full box"

Currently, I am using the following expression:

```
\$(\d*\,\d+).?\d+\s+per\s?(?:full)?\s?box

box = r"\$(\d*\,\d+).?\d+\s+per\s?(?:full)?\s?box" 
boxs = re.findall(box, lines, re.I)
```

But I am returning:
Group 1: "3,10" (It should be 3,100)
Group 2: "3,000" (Correct)

I have fiddled around and tried greedier and more specific expressions, but I am missing something??

Comment: Do you have a snippet of simple test-code that could be posted?

Comment: Yes, I just added it as box and boxs. I am also using it on the regex101.com test site. Thanks

Comment: Should it also recognize prices over one million dollars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your regex with simple modification and it worked

Try this

```
box = r"\$(\d*\,\d*).?\d*\s+per\s?(?:full)?\s?box"
boxs = re.findall(box, lines, re.I)
```

It should output this

```
['3,100', '3,000']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = "$3,100 per box, $3,000.00 per full box"
re.findall('\$(.*?)[per|\.]',a)
```

Out:

```
['3,100 ', '3,000']
```

Comment: This one works as well. I think there is a bug in the regex101.com (python) test site because none of these answers work on it, but they work in my script. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The below regex will solve

```
\$\d+(?:.(\d+))?
```

Answer (score 0):

I took the approach of trying to gobble up the numbers, including any comma or period by treating them as just another pseudo-digit:

```
>>> input="$3,100 per box, $3,000.00 per full box"
>>> box = r"\$([\d,\.]+)+\s+per\s?(?:full)?\s?box" 
>>> boxs = re.findall(box, input, re.I)
>>> boxs
['3,100', '3,000.00']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your expression is more complicated than it should be, if you are looking for numbers only, without the decimals as you mentioned, then the following expression should work:

```
>>> import re
>>>  
>>> m = re.compile('(?<=\$)([0-9]*(?:,)[0-9]*)')
>>> m.findall("$3,100 per box, $3,000.00 per full box, 41,500.00 quantity")
['3,100', '3,000']
```

Basically, it says to look for numbers which have the dollars character preceding them to only capture money valued numbers. You can check it [here](https://regex101.com/r/PyPK9M/1).

Comment: Good point. However, the only issue with this particular application in my script is that there are other lines with dollar amounts that I do not want to pick up. For example, there's a line that says "The total cost of the project is $8,000." I am only searching for the 'per box' dollar amounts in this particular expression.

Comment: Ok, may be you should've mentioned it in your question, to be more specific.